# Python how to add a condition to the groupby while calculating the median of a field?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I need to add a new condition to the following line:

```
train["Age"].fillna(train.groupby("Ticket")["Age"].transform("median"), inplace=True)
```

Currently, its taking the median of the age based on tickets class.

I need to add to this `groupby("Ticket")` another condition, where `train["PrSb"]==0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
train["Age"].fillna(train.loc[train["PrSb"] == 0].groupby("Ticket")["Age"].transform("median"), inplace=True)
```

This adds an extra rowwise filter to the dataframe that is used in the `groupby` operation, which only selects rows where the `PrSb` colum is equal to 0.